# Why aren't all CATransition animation types listed in the documentation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, animation

I was poking around stackoverflow trying to figure out how to do a curl up animation on a layer when I ran into this post: [CATransition page curl from top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652724/catransition-page-curl-from-top)

The author of the post used a constant string 'pageCurl' to define the animation type:
`animation.type = @"pageCurl";`

When looking in the apple documentation for transition animation types only the following types are listed:

```
NSString * const kCATransitionFade;
NSString * const kCATransitionMoveIn;
NSString * const kCATransitionPush;
NSString * const kCATransitionReveal;
```

Did I miss something? Why isn't the curl up transition listed? I tested using "pageCurl" as a transition type in my program and confirmed that it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're not listed, Apple doesn't want you using them.  If you use them, you might get rejected from the app store.

Why doesn't Apple want you using them?  They haven't said, but we can speculate:

1. They want their apps to look better, or at least different, than third-party apps.
2. They haven't settled on the final forms of those transitions yet so they don't want developers relying on them yet.
3. The transitions require too much battery or CPU, so they want to limit their use.

Comment: hmmm that's what I was afraid of.  I'm trying to eventually submit this app and was thinking that would cause problems.  The other option is animation blocks but that creates a headache as I outline here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388215/is-there-an-alternative-way-to-perform-this-animation-using-animation-blocks